# Formatting a manually constructed date in php

Tags: php

I have constructed a series of dates through a loop like so:

```
$months = array();
while($j<=12)
{
    $months[] = '2013- .$j . '-01';
    $j++
}
```

This echos out just as I want it. However, when I use the `date(F, $months[$j])` function its comes out as so January each time. Is this because it isnt a recognised date format? How could I fix this?

Comment: I see your using $j Where does $i comes from? $i is always 0 i believe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use www.php.net/strtotime

`date('F',strtotime($months[$j]))`

Answer (score 2):

Are you incrementing `$j` somewhere outside of what you copied here? Otherwise, there's your answer.

```
$months = array();
$j = 1;
While($j<=12)
{
    $months[] = '2013-' .$j . '-01';
    $j++;
}
```

Plus, you should pass, not a date, but a timestamp:

`date('F', strtotime($months[$j]))`

Also, you may already take in consideration that $j starts at 0, but you are storing them inside `$months` from index 0. So you would change it to:

```
$months = array();
$j = 1;
While($j<=12)
{
    $months[$j] = '2013-' .$j . '-01';
    $j++;
}
```

Comment: yeh, that codes from another loop. I was just showing how I was implementing the date function

Comment: @MattJameson Please post real code wherever possible - too many questions have irrelevant answers because fake code was written with errors that don't apply to the OP's actual code

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$months = array();
$j=1;
While($j<=12)
{
$months[] = '2013-' .$j . '-01';
$j++;
}

$date = new DateTime($months[2]);
echo $date->format('F');
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php